# use spring-data-neo4j in grails get UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: grails, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

i want to use spring-data-neo4j in my grails application.

i've added the `compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-neo4j:3.1.1.RELEASE'` dependency in BuildConfig.

After adding `<neo4j:config storeDirectory="data/graph.db" />` to the `applicationContext.xml`
i get following exception at application start:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration#0': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'conversionService': : Error creating bean with name 'neo4jConversionService' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [protected org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jConversionService() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory has not been injected into @Configuration class; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'neo4jConversionService' defined in class org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [protected org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionService org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration.neo4jConversionService() throws java.lang.Exception] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory has not been injected into @Configuration class`

i use grails 2.4.2

what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the solution was to add `<context:annotation-config/>` to the applicationContext.xml

Comment: Hi @Alexx, did you ever manage to get spring-data-neo4j completely working with grails in the end please?

Comment: No problem any longer, I got it working here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894640/grails-autowire-in-java-class-not-working