# Grails @Autowire in Java class not working

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I have some Java code that I want to turn into a Bean that can be used within Grails controllers & services via dependency injection.  The code is based on that [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-neo4j/) (which works fine when run as a standalone Java application).

Specifically, I have:

```
// WannabeABeanDB.java
package hello;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.neo4j.kernel.impl.util.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.EnableNeo4jRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.config.Neo4jConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.core.GraphDatabase;

import java.io.File;

@Component
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "hello")
public class WannabeABeanDB extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public WannabeABeanDB() {
        setBasePackage("hello");
    }

    @Bean
    GraphDatabaseService graphDatabaseService() {
        return new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase("accessingdataneo4j.db");
    }

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    GraphDatabase graphDatabase;

    public String testThatWeCanAccessDatabase() throws Exception {
        Person greg = new Person("Greg");

        Transaction tx = graphDatabase.beginTx();
        try {
            personRepository.save(greg);
            greg = personRepository.findByName("Greg").toString();
            tx.success();
        } finally {
            tx.close();
        }
        return greg.name;

    }    
}



// Person.java
package hello;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo;

@NodeEntity
public class Person {

    @GraphId Long id;
    public String name;

    public Person() {}
    public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

    public String toString() {
        return this.name;
    }
}



// PersonRepository.java
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, String> {    
    Person findByName(String name);    
}
```

So now I want to use from a controller:

```
// TestController.groovy
package hello

import hello.WannabeABeanDB

class TestController {

WannabeABeanDB graph

def index() { 
    render graph.test()
    }
}
```

I've set (within Config.groovy):

```
grails.spring.bean.packages = ['hello']
```

However, when I do a grails run-app, Grails crashes with a very long error message that says it can't work with a null database.  I don't believe the @Autowire is being picked up for either PersonRepository or for graphDatabase.

So the question is, what more do I need to do to be able to write use Java code (within src/java) as a Bean within a Grails controller or service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- Editing answer based on the sample code --

I suspect the issue is related to how component scanning works with Grails and Java code mixed together. It might also
have to do with the order in which beans are created in this situation and proxying of classes behind the scenes.

I made the following changes to make this work:

1. I went back to neo4j xml configuration and added a grails-app/conf/resources.xml with necessary neo4j configuration.
2. Removed the @EnableNeo4jRepositories annotation from the class
3. Took out statement from Config.groovy -- grails.spring.bean.packages = ['grailsSdn4j']

For others' reference, the neo4j configuration in resources.xml looks like this:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:neo4j="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/neo4j/spring-neo4j.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <neo4j:config storeDirectory="target/data/db" base-package="grailsSdn4j"/>

    <neo4j:repositories base-package="grailsSdn4j"/>
</beans>
```

Comment: Thanks, the GraphDatabase bean is not provided/written by me; it's part of spring-data-neo4j.  I've tried putting various things into resources.groovy, e.g. beans = { graphDatabase(GraphDatabase) {} }, but without success.  Do you have any suggestions as to what to try please?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your comment and the code posted above. Basically, the graphDatabase is injected normally in your Java code (Spring DI) and then you register your POJO (WannabeABeanDB) in grails application context.

Comment: No, I can get WannabeABeanDB to load in Grails ok.  What is failing is the "@Autowired GraphDatabase graphDatabase;" statement: graphDatabase remains null.  Your answer helped me fix another problem elsewhere (thanks!), but sadly it doesn't fix this problem.

Comment: so the graphDatabase bean would be created and injected by Spring?

It looks like the @EnableNeo4jRepositories annotation will scan base package "hello" for repositories and auto generate the implementation. I am guessing that the way the annotation and scanning works in the Spring Java application doesn't exactly work out the same way with your grails application. If we can figure out how that bean is supposed to be created, then we could find a solution to this problem.

If it's possible to put your code on github, I could take a look later today.

Comment: I've put the code on github here: https://github.com/johnlondon/grailsSdn4  I can't for the life of me work out what I need to do to get the @Autowired statements to work.  Any suggestions you can offer would be gratefully received - I'm sure others out there would like to be able to use spring-data-neo4j and Grails.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: I got it working! I updated my comment above and I also created a pull request for your github repository (you should be able to pull my changes and merge them with your code).

Or you can just checkout my version: https://github.com/jigishpa/grailsSdn4j

Comment: You, Sir, are awesome, thank you so much!  I've made a couple of small amendments to get the TestController to link to the Java class and to remove some unnecessary code from the main class now that you've added configuration code to spring/resources.xml.  The updated version is on Github.